# Modifying Python script tool in standard toolbox file (*.tbx)?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I am trying to modify an existing custom ArcMap toolbox (change input parameters, doc, etc.) but I just can't do anything with the .tbx file.

I see Python code in there but it seem to be a binary file. The "edit" "Refresh" and "Check syntax" menu items on right click are greyed out.

All I can do is edit the script tool itself (it pops up the script in notepad)

So how do you modify the .tbx?

Comment: In ArcCatalog. The toolbox is an Esri format and needs Esri software to open it. Perhaps the toolbox is locked.

Comment: Is it a custom .tbx or is it one of the toolboxes supplied with ArcMap?

Comment: It's a custom toolbox. https://bitbucket.org/wankoelias/maptogarmincustommap

Comment: Ahhh OK I got it! I expected something else... I don't know why I did't see that.

Comment: @GobTron Didn't see what?  Please expand into an answer if you've got one to add

Comment: Yes, of course I will explain in an anwser.

Answer (score 3):

To modify the GUI or the code of a custom toolbox (.tbx) in ArcMap:

- Open the Catalog window and go to the toolbox
- Expand the toolbox (the '+' at the left)
- Right click on the script tool and click 'Properties...'
- There, you have different tabs to edit the parameters, the validation script, etc.

I do have a bug though when applying any modification to the Validation script, even if I don't change anything at all in the file.

Comment: Note -- you're getting down votes because you're confusing script tools inside a TBX with a PYT (which is a python toolbox, a python script itself). From your question, "check syntax" and "refresh" are only options of the PYT.